# Getting req.body empty using form-data in postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, form-data

when i post request using `postman` by form data like this, i got empty object in my express js  :

[image]

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, 'public/images/course');
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        console.log(req.file)
        if (request.files) {
            console.log(file)
           // TODO: consider adding file type extension
           fileExtension = file.originalname.split('.')[1]
           return callback(null, `${request.path}-${request.files[0]._id.toString()}.${fileExtension}`);
        }
        // fallback to the original name if you don't have a book attached to the request yet. 
        return callback(null, file.originalname) 
    }
});

var uploadImg = multer({storage : storage}).single('thumbnail')

router.post('/course',  async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // console logs empty object {}
    try{
    const course = new Course({
                name : req.body.name,
                thumbnail : 'placeholder'
            })  
            uploadImg(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err.message);
                  // An error occurred when uploading
                  return
                }
                console.log('Everything went fine');
                // Everything went fine
              })
    }catch(e){
        res.status().send()
    }  
})
```

and i cant use multer before to parse data because first i wanna generate an id by mongoose then i use multer like above.

for example i can't do it like :

```
router.post('/course', upload.single(), async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // console logs empty object {}
    try{
    const course = new Course({
                name : req.body.name,
                thumbnail : 'placeholder'
            })  
            uploadImg(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err.message);
                  // An error occurred when uploading
                  return
                }
                console.log('Everything went fine');
                // Everything went fine
              })
    }catch(e){
        res.status().send()
    }  
})
```

it gives an ERROR : unexpected field.

so is there any way to get my req.body data first so i can generate my mongoose id and then upload the image

```
//index.js

const express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer');
require('./db/mongoose')
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')
const taskRouter = require('./routers/task')
const courseRouter = require('./routers/course')

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000



// // for parsing application/json
 app.use(bodyParser.json()) 

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(express.json())
 app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(userRouter)
app.use(taskRouter)
app.use(courseRouter)


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('connected succefully')
})
```

Comment: Can you add the your main app file, i would like to see the modules you're using. Maybe its something related to `body-parser` lib.

Comment: here it is @Danizavtz

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of express for sending requests using form-data, you need to add `multer` on your server-side. Like that:

```
npm install --save multer
```

Then in your main server file add these lines.

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
app.use(upload.array());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [express-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-busboy) to parse postman form-data.

```
var app = express();
var expressBusboy = require('express-busboy');
expressBusboy.extend(app);
```

Comment: why express >=4.16 is not working with body-parser . I tried this also app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); . But finaly expressBusboy helps me

Comment: the file is not being read by this why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `express` **version >= 4.16**
You can for sure remove the `body-parser` lib.
You can also remove from package.json
One of the new features from express `4.16 was bundle express with body-parser. 
If it's the case, remove the lines with body-parser lib, and use only body parser that comes bundled with express:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If it's **version <=4.16**
also install body-parser in you package.json

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
...
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

You should stick with one but not mix them.

Comment: yes first i was using expess parser only but still getting empty object . didn't help

Comment: where are your `multer` declaration to handle files? Can you just remove the file from postman and do the tests again?

Comment: see i updated the post with my multer declaration and  i tried to test again but didn't resolved @Danizavtz